# $.ajax has no request payload for absolute filesystem path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, electron

<sup>Note: I explain the strange urls in a spoiler below.</sup>

Electron@2.0.4
jquery@3.3.1

When I try to use $.ajax to an absolute path from within Electron jquery seems to get rid of my payload. I use the following:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test/anything?func=ajax",
      method: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"}),
    });

    fetch("/test/anything?func=fetch", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      body: JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"})
    });
```

They produce the following requests:

[image: ajax]

[image: fetch]

As you can see, the ajax call has no payload while the fetch does. Does anyone know a way to fix this or if there is a reason for this behavior?

---

As for the strange URL, I use a service worker to forward urls that start with `/test` to `http://localhost`, that's working properly as pictured below. Localhost is just for testing, I have a local copy of [httpbin](https://github.com/requests/httpbin) running on docker.

I am doing this to port a web app to electron so the codebases can be the same, aside from index.html changes and adding sw.js.

[image: sw]

Comment: Spoiler completely ruined the URL experience for me. 0/10.

Comment: They're not relative URLs, they're absolute filesystem paths.

Comment: You are correct, they are absolute urls. Edited

Comment: You cannot make an AJAX request to a `file://` path, for security reasons. You need to run your code on a webserver. You can easily install XAMPP or IIS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is inside Electron. Are you suggesting I host the files from a webserver (like express) from my main process and then load localhost for the window?  

Edit: Also, why can I make a request using fetch to the same endpoint and it works as I expected it but the ajax call doesn't?

Comment: Why are you using a spoiler?  I have removed it.  If you actually think you need it, feel free to state why and rollback my edit.

Comment: Here you are sending data as GET, but you are using post, and you have missed data type json

Comment: @zero298 I had it in a spoiler because it wasn't very important to the overall question, but if someone wanted an explanation to why I was trying to make requests with those urls from within electron they could look at the hidden text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rory's comment above, I found a solution. I installed express and added the an `express.js` file to the project root, with the contents:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('.'))
app.listen(3000)
```

Using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/maximilian-lindsey/a446a7ee87838a62099d), I added the following to various places in my `main.js` file:

```
const express = require('./express.js'); //<

function createWindow () {
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/index.html'); //<
}
```

The service worker still gets the request, and it replaces the `http://localhost:3000/test` with `http://localhost`

ajax:
[image: ajax]

service worker:
[image: sw]

The service worker also sends an OPTIONS request to make sure cross domain is allowed, while the fetch's request doesn't. This seems to be because the ajax request has an X-Requested-With header, while the fetch doesn't.